# Alphabetical sort using elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, sorting, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I wounder if there any way or setting to perform an alphabetical sort in elasticsearch. I've got a field and I want to perform sort in descending order over it. Elastic performs it lexicographically. What I get:

```
Company name
Customer name
company address
```

What I want to get:

```
Company name
company address
Customer name
```

I found that I can create a custom analyser, but maybe there can be a better option?

Comment: If you don't use any analyzer Elasticsearch uses Standard Analyzer and it has a lowercase filter. In that case, I guess, you will get the sorted result correctly. But this result do not works for unicode characters. You can check the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-collations.html article if you don't see.

Comment: yeah excatly, @Yauheni you can build different analyzer for the field and then you can tell es to sort on that field.

Answer (score 1):

use [multifields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) to index the text field as lowercased keyword with fielddata true where you can sort.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "keyword_lowercase": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "text": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": { 
              "type":     "text",
              "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase",
              "fielddata": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "text.raw": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```